# How do you deal with upvotes on answers that are just farming?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

Take a look at the answers at the bottom of this question:

[How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Some of them are 3 years old, all of them have 1 upvote.  Most of them don't deserve it.  I'm guessing different newbies are farming for upvotes by putting answers on questions and getting their friend to upvote them.  How do you catch that in an automated fashion and put it to rest.

Comment: The serial upvoting script stops repeated offenders, but there's not much to prove with a single offense.

Comment: For example, there are several other knowledgeable people in the tags I frequent (`iOS`, `objective-c`, `c++`, `c`), and we frequently cross vote each other's answers if they are good. That doesn't mean we're gaming for rep, we're just upvoting good answers, and they happen to be from people who interact a lot.

Comment: That is a question with over one hundred thousand views. Why do you assume that not a single one of those many thousands of people upvoted those answers, even if you disagree with the upvoting?

Comment: Take a look at the answer by Sumheet Ghopal, he basically tells you about how to disable it in IE, clearly not a programming question/response.  Yet he has an upvote.  Some of these are clearly not worth an upvote, especially when the answer is 3 years newer question and doesn't actually answer it.

Comment: @Mark0978 the other thing you have to consider is the 'first posts' queue. Many reviewers will simply upvote an answer and just move on, so they can get their badges. It's really a terrible thing, but there isn't much we can do.

Comment: Richard protected the question 2 minutes ago.  That's one way.

Comment: @Richard, I'm happy to see we can blame the review drones in this case too.

Answer (score 4):

The question itself is a few years old, so I don't really see how the age of the answers suggests this is upvote farming. As a matter of fact, there's a badge devoted to answering old inactive questions: Necromancer. So that's a behavior which is actually encouraged.

If the questions are particularly low quality, just down vote them like you would any other.

If you think this question is a problem - that it's old enough and contains enough answers to hide "farming" behavior -  you can flag it to be locked or protected.

Comment: Necromancer really is for old, unloved questions, not the ones that have already been adequately answered.

Comment: Adequate? We need at least five more answers stating `autocomplete='off'` before it's satisfiably answered

Comment: @random - If community members do their part and flag questions to be protected or locked, I think it can be adequate. But that's kind of a but "if".

Comment: @RobertHarvey hm of [9 Necromancers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer?userid=165773) I've got at MSO, 7 have fairly nicely upvoted old answers - do these 7 qualify as "adequately answered"?

Comment: @gnat: At MSO?  Where votes are the red pill, and the moon is made of cheese?

Comment: Isn't locking only for questions that have historical value, but are not good examples of what we want on SO? (On a unrelated note, I must read far to many locked questions if I can spew that off the top of my head.)

Comment: @ryan - I would have assumed that to be the purpose of "protected". "Protected" and "Locked" seem to be separate things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @ryan You are describing the "historical lock", but I should note that there are there are other locks as well, which may be applied for other reasons. (Not that they are appropriate in this case.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Richard's fine answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176659/50049), remember that every new user needs to work to lift the [new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) and will soon find themselves wanting to be able to [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Given the uniqueness of our system and that many of our users come from backgrounds where [uncertainty avoidance](http://www.clearlycultural.com/geert-hofstede-cultural-dimensions/uncertainty-avoidance-index/) is high, it's only natural for some to initially participate in answering questions by providing answers to a few 'sure things'.

There's no real *harm* in doing this, or the subsequent brief bump to the front page that the question receives. In order for old content to be well curated, a little churn is needed from time to time. Additionally, late answers and first posts by new users are churned through `/review` to make sure they're up to shape - we've [touched on this before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135191/should-a-user-with-less-than-10-rep-be-allowed-to-answer-extremely-old-questions/135192#135192). We do *hope* that each new answer to an old question brings something new to the table, but that's not always the case.

If an old question continues to receive *nearly identical* answers long after it was asked and answered satisfactorily, moderators and 15k + users can protect the question, requiring anyone wishing to answer it again to have at least 10 reputation.